# Is there a way to speed up the following opencv operations without GPU?

Tags: c++, opencv

Can I get any suggestions on how to speed up this process of generating a mask implemented in C++, below?

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std::chrono;

void main() {
    
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("image.png");
    cv::Mat mask;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    const double r = 0.95;

    image.convertTo(mask, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255);

    cv::Mat bgr[3];
    cv::split(mask, bgr);

    cv::max(bgr[0], bgr[1], bgr[0]);
    cv::max(bgr[0], bgr[2], bgr[0]);

    cv::subtract(bgr[0], r, bgr[0]);
    cv::max(bgr[0], 0, bgr[0]);
    cv::divide(bgr[0], (1 - r), bgr[0]);
    cv::min(bgr[0], 1.0, bgr[0]);

    mask = bgr[0];

    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "mask generated in: " << duration.count() << " [ms]" << std::endl;
}
```

I am rusty at C++ and I translated this from the python implementation below.

```py
r=0.95

img_LQ = cv2.imread('image.png')
img_LQ = img_LQ.astype(np.float32) / 255.

H, W, C = img_LQ.shape
if H%32!=0 or W%32!=0:
    H_new = int(np.ceil(H / 32) * 32)
    W_new = int(np.ceil(W / 32) * 32)
    img_LQ = cv2.resize(img_LQ, (W_new, H_new))

mask = np.max(img_LQ, axis=2)

mask = np.minimum(1.0, np.maximum(0, mask - r) / (1 - r))

mask = mask * 255
```

I figured generally opencv operations are optimized and I stuck to it. Using a different library is also pretty frowned upon in this use-case.

I figure it might be faster using opencv with CUDA suport, through GpuMat, but the upload time of the image to gpu takes too long.

grouping operations, using GPU

Comment: Do you need the 32bit precision ? Running everything in 8bit if you can should be significantly (?) faster. 

If not, move the conversion after the split and the two max-functions at least. That way you only need to convert 1 channel and compute less in it.

Comment: if C++ makes you reconsider breathing, you can just stick with python, and use `numba`. tack a `@njit(parallel=True)` onto your function, and try rewriting any library functions as pure python. you'll get C performance. numba on pure python code can definitely be faster than generic numpy functions. it may not beat OpenCV functions though because those can use various acceleration techniques.

Comment: what's the purpose of the `resize()`? that entirely resamples the picture, while the purpose appears to be merely to make the image size a multiple of 32. you could just **crop** the picture... it's not the same but it's a trivial operation.

Comment: the np.max(axis=2) is probably part of cvtColor(BGR2HSV), the luminance channel. you don't need all the data from cvtColor but it's cheap enough to call. -- use single-channel result Mats. writing packed data is cheaper than writing in strides. -- dump most of those explicit opencv calls. Mats have operators overloaded. just write the expressions.

Comment: what performance _do_ you get right now with your code, and why do you need more than that?

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, right now I'm getting 400 milliseconds, on an Intel i9-9900KF with 16GB RAM

I'm trying to get it faster because it's part of a the processing of each frame, in a hopefully Real-Time processing

Comment: @nick I think you're right and I don't need 32bit precision. I'll try it on 8bit and see the difference

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz if you don't mind, could you elaborate on this:


"" -- use single-channel result Mats. writing packed data is cheaper than writing in strides. -- dump most of those explicit opencv calls. Mats have operators overloaded.  just write the expressions ""



I am curious and I think it might help me other matters too.

Comment: nevermind the first part. the split() call creates new matrices, and they're all packed. -- instead of `cv::subtract(bgr[0], r, bgr[0]);` you can just write `bgr[0] = bgr[0] - r;` (or try `bgr[0] -= r;`). also explore OpenCV's core functions. there is saturating math somewhere in there. you should use those calls explicitly because then you don't need to convert to a wider data type, trying to avoid negative values. the saturating math operation will just take care of that.